# How can I keep my gpg private key on removable media in Windows?

Tags: encryption, cygwin, gnupg

I use GPG through Cygwin on Windows. I don't want to store my key on my laptop as a convenient file for a casual tech-savvy thief to grab if they steal the machine, so I'd like to keep it on a USB that I can keep with my house keys (I'm aware that this isn't hyper-secure, and I'm sure the keys would be forensically-retrievable from the machine, but I don't really care about that).

How can I do this? I want GPG to look for my keyring elsewhere, not .gnupg. I don't think a command-line flag to GPG would do it, because I'm using programs that invoke GPG and can't forward the flags.

Am I missing a configuration option?

Comment: Is it possible?  Yes;  There is no difference between storing the key on the hdd or a flash drive.  You just have to point it to that directory.

Comment: Please read the post. By default, GPG looks for my keystore in ~/.gnupg. I need to tell it to look in (for example) e:\keystore instead, and I don't know how.

Comment: So change where GNUPG looks for it.

Comment: Yes. You have identified the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move *all of `.gnupg`* to your USB stick. The native GnuPG for Windows builds have a registry setting, but the most portable option (working with both native and Cygwin versions) is to set the `GNUPGHOME` environment variable.

If your Windows version has `setx`, run it from the Command Prompt:

```
C:\> setx GNUPGHOME A:\Private\gnupg
```

Otherwise, open the "System" Control Panel item (`sysdm.cpl`), go to the "Advanced" tab, and add the environment variable there.

Log out & log in again to make sure all programs have picked up the change.